# make the output more sparse

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I trained a MLP typed neural network for a prediction model. The predicted value is shown as follows. Is that possible to let the predicted value become more sparse.I would like those points corresponding to small peaks (painted with yellow) are enforced to have more smaller values. In other words, I would like this predicted sequence has smaller number of peaks. I can add a threshold to do the similar work. But I prefer to let model learn it automatically. I tried L1 type of activity regularizer. But it did not help a lot.

```python
model= Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(60,32, strides=1, activation='relu',padding='causal',input_shape=(64,1)))
model.add(Conv1D(80,10, strides=1, activation='relu',padding='causal'))
#model.add(Conv1D(100,5, strides=1, activation='relu',padding='causal'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(Dense(300,activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.01),activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1,activation='linear'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you think that the smaller peaks are caused by overfitting to the training data, you can try to add a `Dropout` layer instead of your `activity regularizer`. For example:

```
model.add(Dropout(0.2, input_shape=(300,)))
```